# show popup window on tableview cell double click JavaFX

Tags: java, popup, javafx, tableview, cell

I have a table, one column, n rows. I need to show popup window on double click to tableview cell. Each row have own popup.

Answer (score 2):

```
yourCell.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                if (mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
                    if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {

                        //codes to show your Popup window

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```